# C program does not work as expected when stdin is supplied using cat

Tags: c, stdin, cat

Here is a short C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void){

    char cmd;

    while(scanf("%c", &cmd) != EOF){

        if(cmd == 'q'){
            printf("Thanks\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

When the following program is executed and value of `cmd` is typed using keyboard, everything works as expected.

```
$ ./catproblem
q
Thanks
$
```

However, when I am trying to pipe the input using `cat`, the program doesn't terminate right away when `q` is entered. For some reason it waits for any other input and only then terminates.

```
$ cat | ./catproblem
q
Thanks
anything
$
```

What causes this behavior? And can this be fixed, so that the program works as expected if `cat` is used for input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `cat` has not terminated, and your shell (`bash`) waits for all processes in the pipeline to terminate before continuing.  When you type the line with `anything`, `cat` attempts to write to the pipe, gets a SIGPIPE signal, and terminates.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for explanation!